# Hyper-V 2016 VM won't start due to RemoteFX Manager error?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, remotefx, hyper-v-manager

I did a clean install of Server 2016 + Hyper-V role on a new server with a Xeon v4, 100GB+ RAM, and a RemoteFX capable NVidia Quadro card with 6GB GDDR. *(If it works I'll use the bare Hyper-V server 2016, this is for testing so full server + role is OK).*

The install was fine. I enabled roles and features, which was fine as well, then installed the Quadro drivers. Hyper-V Manager recognised and accepted the Quadro immediately and reports it can provide RemoteFX services to VMs with it. So I created a simple Gen2 VM to test it out. The VM installer ISO is Win 8.1 Enterprise, which is RemoteFX compatible.

The VM refuses to start if I include a RemoteFX 3D adapter in the hardware. It tries for maybe 1-3 minutes, then reports error 32788 in a GUI popup, that it couldn't start. If I remove the virtual RemoteFX adapter it starts fine.

The Hyper-V VMMS and Worker event logs show various errors:

- Error 32613 **"The VM Management Service could not start the RemoteFX Manager... Try restarting the VM Management Service. Error message: An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist. Status Code 20."**.
- Error 4120 **"Description cannot be found... Locale specific resource for the desired message not present... Underlying XML for the message is not well formed"**
- Error 32607 **"The required GPU resources could not be accessed. This server cannot run as a RemoteFX host without a GPU. Verify that the GPU is correctly installed"**
- Error 15350 **"The virtualisation infrastructure driver (VID) is not running"**
- Error 12010 **"Description cannot be found... Locale specific resource for the desired message not present."**
- Error 12018 **"Synthetic 3D Display Controller: Failed to power on ... because a worker session could not be created"**

I've excluded the usual causes (disk space, incompatible CPU/card) and cannot find any resource to troubleshoot further. No device errors are showing in the VM or hypervisor settings pages. The server has all applicable roles for Hyper-V and desktop virtualisation enabled. All devices in "Device Manager" (including the MS Hyper-V VID driver under "System") report as working correctly, so it doesn't seem to be a driver startup error.  My entire activity has pretty much been: install Server 2016 + updates, enable Hyper-V/desktop virtualisation roles+features, install Quadro driver, set up Hyper-V, and create VM, so there isn't much scope for weird stuff to have gone on.

Some web pages refer to RemoteFX permission issues that can cause VMs not to start, but usually if so, this is stated explicitly (according to pages I've seen). In my case there's no explicit statement of a permissions issue, although the "token" and the statement that resources "could not be accessed" strongly suggests some kind of permissions token issue might be going on. But no hint what, if so.

I can't find more info, and there's no other references to this error online that seem relevant. I have no idea where to look to fix it, or trace what's causing the failure.

Comment: same problem, cant find anyting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a tip that the graphics card driver needs to be installed before Hyper-V takes over the system (i.e., installs itself as a hypervisor, for example using Server 2016 with the Hyper-V role for testing).

I reinstalled Server 2016, but this time I installed the card drivers before adding the Hyper-V role, not afterwards. I'm sure the driver can be installed afterwards, but this solved the problem immediately.